# Prevent modal duplication for edit in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.3

I'm trying to to editing using bootstrap modals. My problems is that my current way is including the modals in the foreach loop.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" name="input[]" value="{{ $user->name }}"></td>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ $user->role->name }}
        </td>

        <td> 
        @if($user->team_id)
            {{ $user->team->name }}
        @else
            {{ 'N/A' }}
        @endif
        </td>

        <td>
            @if($user->is_active == 0)
                {{ 'Blocked' }}
            @elseif($user->is_active == 1)
                {{ 'Active' }}
            @endif
        </td>

        <td>
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-edit-{{ $user->id }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>  
        </td> 
        @include('partials.modals.editUser')
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

And my modal looks like this

```
<div id="modal-edit-{{$user->id}}" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                <div class="col-sm "><h3 class="text-center m-t-none m-b">Edit User</h3>

                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.update', $user->id )}}">
                    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group"><label>Name</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}"></div>

                        <div class="form-group"><label>Email</label> <input type="email" placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control" name="email"  value="{{ $user->email }}"></div>


                        <div class="form-group"><label>Password</label> <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password"  value="{{ $user->password }}"></div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="role">Activation</label>
                                {{ Form::select('activation', 

                                ['1' =>'Active', 
                                '0' => 'Blocked',
                                ], $user->is_active, array('class' => 'chosen-select', 'data-placeholder' => 'Choose Activation', 'tab-index' => '4')) }}
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="role">Select Role</label>
                                {{ Form::select('role', 
                                [1 =>'Admin', 
                                2 => 'Team Leader',
                                3 => 'Team Member',
                                ], $user->role_id, array('class' => 'chosen-select', 'data-placeholder' => 'Choose a role', 'tab-index' => '4')) }}
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group"><label>Team</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Team" class="form-control" name="team_id" value="{{ $user->team_id }}"> </div>

                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-block" onclick="pressOnlyOnce()" value="Save Changes">

                     </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I edit my data using only one modal so that I can place it outside the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

You could move the include outside the `@foreach` loop and add your variables to the button that triggers the modal to use them with javascript.

The button should look like this:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-edit-{{ $user->id }}" data-user-id="{{ $user->id }}" data-user-active="{{ $user->active }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
```

Comment: i already tried using this method, but I also have modals with over 10 variables. that would make by <a> really long. is there another way to do this?

Comment: You could use ajax to get the data directly from the server when the modal opens.